# Odoo 8 "message_id" column in "mail_message" table

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

I was writing an external app in python that uses the message system in odoo.
So, I need to use, the mail_message, and the mail_notification tables.

I tried to put elements individually via INSERT into the table filling the necessary elements to make this work, and it works perfectly, the messages appear in the "inbox" of messages in Odoo and the notification appears correctly.

But checking the rest of the fields in this table, I see that message_id got a tag format (between <>) and a series of numbers (that I haven't found any correlation) followed by "-openerp-'res_id'-'model'-@'company'".

So, I don't know how to fill this field, my proofs determined that is not a necessary field, but in a serious implementation I don't know if left this field empty can cause some issues.

Anyone can explain me the reason of this field and how to fill it?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the XMLRPC API from Odoo for that requirement? How do you login users by your approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the code in tools/mail.py and do something similar

```
def generate_tracking_message_id(res_id):
    """Returns a string that can be used in the Message-ID RFC822 header field

       Used to track the replies related to a given object thanks to the "In-Reply-To"
       or "References" fields that Mail User Agents will set.
    """
    try:
        rnd = random.SystemRandom().random()
    except NotImplementedError:
        rnd = random.random()
    rndstr = ("%.15f" % rnd)[2:]
    return "<%.15f.%s-openerp-%s@%s>" % (time.time(), rndstr, res_id, socket.gethostname())
```